# find the difference betwwen two dates by using a single function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In this code i try to get the difference between two date and time 
ex(09/05/2014 09:10:00 - 09/05/2014 11:18:00 ) it should return 78 minutes with a single function for multiple textboxes but unfortunately this piece of code is not working can some one suggest me the correct code or is there is any alternative way to perform this function , thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TODO supply a title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="JS/datejquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("id^='endTime'".change(function(){
   var index = $(this).attr('id').replace('endTime','');
alert(index);
   var startTime = $('#startTime'+index).val();
   var endTime = $(this).val();

   $('#result'+index).val(endTime-startTime);
 });
 } );
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="wrs">
 <input type="text" name="time1" id= "startTime1" class="num-box type1"  />
 <input type="text" name="time2" id = "endTime1" class="num-box type2" />
 <input type="text" name="result1" class="num-box type5"  />
 <input type="text" name="startTime2" id= "time3" class="num-box type3"  />
 <input type="text" name="endTime2" id = "time4" class="num-box type4"        />
 <input type="text" name="result2" class="num-box type6"  />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the brackets.

```
    $("[id^='endTime']").change(function(){

   var index = $(this).attr('id').slice(7);
   alert(index);
   var startTime = $('#startTime'+index).val();
   var endTime = $(this).val();

   $('#result'+index).val(endTime-startTime);
 });
```

Comment: thank you sudharsan, Its working but the value is returning as NaN wat i have to do to make it as value

Comment: try with parseInt like this $('#result'+index).val(parseInt(endTime , 10) - parseInt(startTime , 10));